# Trouble getting help in vim

Tags: fedora, vim

I have just finished the `vimtutor` and everything went fine except for the last part (Lesson 7.1: Getting Help). I type `:help` and the help manual is shown as it is supposed to. But then I try (as suggested) the commands `:help w`, `:help c_CTRL-D`, `:help insert-index` and `:help user-manual` and the following appears at the bottom left of the screen:

```
E434: Can't find tag pattern
Press Enter or type command to continue
```

I press enter and a bunch of nonsensical characters appear on the screen, but I don't get any help. Why could this be happening and how can I fix it?

**Note:** I'm running Fedora 20 and have the following packages installed: `vim-common`, `vim-minimal`, `vim-enhanced`, `vim-filesystem`.

---

Okay so I tried running `vim --version` and this is what I get:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Sep 11 2013 12:26:40)
Included patches: 1-27
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I/usr/local/include  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches  -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--enable-new-dtags  -Wl,-z,relro  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -lnsl  -lselinux  -lncurses -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,--enable-new-dtags  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
```

I think it's quite the same you have. Where else could the problemm be?

Comment: FYI: It appears you've got two separate "accounts". I suggest you go through creating a full account, and then email team@stackoverflow.com or team@stackexchange.com and ask them to merge them all together.

Comment: Or use the [contact us](http://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the buttom of the page

Comment: I don't see anything different (that concerns me) b/w your output and mine. I'd bring this up with the package maintainer(s) of Fedora, LMK I can assist if you don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I wasn't using the `vim-enhanced` binary.

Ensure `vim-enhanced` is installed first

```
rpm -qa | grep vim-enhanced
```

If it's not installed then

```
sudo yum install vim-enhanced
```

On my system it listed the package `vim-enhanced-7.4.629-5.el6.x86_64`

Then look where it put the vim binary which should be `/usr/bin/vim`

```
rpm -ql vim-enhanced-7.4.629-5.el6.x86_64
```

Update symlink to point to location shown for vim in above command

```
ln /usr/bin/vim /bin/vim
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss some of the documentation. On my system (non-Fedora) those are in package `vim-runtime`.

For instance `:help c_CTRL_D` accesses `cmdline.txt` and comes from that package. The `:help` comes from `help.txt`

Comment: Okay so I think it's better to ask directly on the Fedora forum. Thanks.

Comment: @LucaPandelli - I use Fedora and the files that provide this help are not in a sep. package as Zelda is suggesting. They're part of vim-common, so your issue lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is either something broken in the packaging of the vim RPMs or in your environment. I'm running Fedora 19 and have the following RPMs installed.

```
$ rpm -aq | grep vim
vim-enhanced-7.4.027-2.fc19.x86_64
vim-filesystem-7.4.027-2.fc19.x86_64
vim-common-7.4.027-2.fc19.x86_64
vim-minimal-7.4.027-2.fc19.x86_64
vim-vimoutliner-0.3.6-3.fc19.noarch
vim-X11-7.4.027-2.fc19.x86_64
```

Repeating your commands within `vim` and `gvim` work fine for me.

#### vim --version

Running this command produces the following setup/configurations for my setup.

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Sep 11 2013 12:28:28)
Included patches: 1-27
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I/usr/local/include  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches  -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -Wl,-z,relro  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -lnsl  -lselinux  -lncurses -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -fstack-protector  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
```